# GWT - Get the value of a checkbox from a servlet

Tags: servlets, gwt, checkbox

I'm trying to get the value of a checkbox from a field (whether it is checked or not).
The form method is post and the encoding is multipart because I'm uploading a file with the same form action.

I succeeded on getting the values of other fields (simple TextBox and even the file from the FileUpload Widget).
However, when it comes to the values of a CheckBox widget, I'm always getting the value "on" ...
At first I thought it was "on" when it was checked and "off" when it was unchecked. However, I'm always getting "on" no matter what.

The form is a very simple one so no need to show it to you, instead, here is the code I'm using to get fields values from the servlet:

```
FileItemIterator ierator = uplaod.getItemIterator(request);
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    FileItemStream item = iterator.next();

    if (item.isFormField()) {
        String fieldValue = Streams.asString(item.openStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous as you're basically implying that this problem is caused by using GWT and/or multipart/form-data instead of "plain servlet" and/or "plain HTTP request". To exclude one and other, are you in first place aware of the fact that webbrowsers don't send values of unchecked checkboxes at all? This is completely regardless of web framework and HTML form encoding used.

Comment: I didn't know that web browsers don't send values of unchecked checkboxes. I will sleep less stupid tonight ^^ thx
However, I checked both cases (checked and unchecked but I always got the value "on" from the checkbox...)

Comment: You were right ! It's all about how web browsers handle checkboxes ... So if I get the form field from the servlet I put the value to true, otherwise false ! Thx :)